# Access VBA - TreeView Control - AfterLabelEdit Event

Tags: ms-access, vba, treeview

I've got a treeview control in my form. I would like to be able to edit the node in the tree and push the change to Access DB. However, I'm having trouble finding an appropriate event. [MSDN treeview events reference page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview_methods.aspx) advices *AfterLabelEdit*, but I am not able to get it to work. Is anyone aware of any workaround/solution?
Snippet of the code I use (I've added *onClick* and *onDblClick* for comparison, as they work):

```
Private Sub xMyTreeview_Click() 'OK
 testit
End Sub
Private Sub xMyTreeview_DblClick() 'OK
 EditLabel
End Sub

Private Sub xMyTreeview_AfterLabelEdit() 'Problem
 AfterLabel
End Sub

Sub EditLabel()
 Me.xMyTreeview.StartLabelEdit
End Sub

Sub AfterLabel()
 MsgBox prompt, vbOKOnly, "afterlabel"
End Sub

Sub testit()
 Dim nodSelected As MSComctlLib.Node ' a variable for the currently selected node

 Set nodSelected = Me.xMyTreeview.SelectedItem ' get the currently selected node

 NodesStrLength = Len(nodSelected.Key)
 Dim NodeStr As String
 Dim StrToChange As String
 StrToChange = nodSelected.Key
 NodeStr = Mid(StrToChange, 2, NodesStrLength - 1)

 Me.txtNodeID = NodeStr
 Me.sfrmDOCNODE.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link is to the .net Windows Form Treeview but `MSComctlLib` is the older Visual Basic Common Controls: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443023(v=vs.60).aspx

Note the event prototype is different; if you don't declare it with the correct arguments it will never get raised;

```
Private Sub object_AfterLabelEdit(cancel As Integer, newstring As String)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This answer solved my problem back in April.